# Error with using mongoose package for connection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser...

```
{ useUnifiedTopology: true },
{ useNewUrlParser: true }
```

Comment: can you share the code which has problem??

Comment: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/deprecations.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because every option passed should be one object 
like this

```
{ useUnifiedTopology: true ,
 useNewUrlParser: true }
```

Full Connection could be like

```
 mongoose.connect(URL, {
    useUnifiedTopology: true ,
    useNewUrlParser: true
}
).then(() => {
    console.log('Successfully connected to the database');
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(`Could not connect to the database.. ${err}`);
    process.exit();
});
```